# Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php

I am trying to convert an array to its value.

I am getting this:

```
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 31 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 32 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 33 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 34 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 35 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 36 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 37 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 38 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 39 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 40 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 41 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 42 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 43 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 44 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 45 )
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ReadNotes\mynote.php on line 42

Array ( [0] => 46 )
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

//Starting session

session_start();

//Includes mass includes containing all the files needed to execute the full script
//Also shows homepage elements without customs

include ('includes/mass.php');

//Set the  session variable

$username = $_SESSION['username'];


//Check to see if logged in

    if (isset($username))
    
        {

            //Check all databases assoc with the notes for username submissions
            
            $sql_for_username_submission = "SELECT note_id FROM notes WHERE user = '$username' ORDER BY note_id";

            $get_data = mysql_query($sql_for_username_submission);
            
            while ($data_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data))
            
                    {    //Get name_id's in arrays
                            
                         $name_id_array = $data_row; 
                         
                         //Make each one display all information associated with it.
                         
                         foreach($name_id_array as $name_id)
                         
                                  { 
                                        //Convert name_id array to its id number
                                        
                                        $number_on_name_id = array_values($name_id);    
                                  
                                        echo $number_on_name_id."</br>";                                        

                                  } 
                        
                         print_r (array_values($name_id_array));
                        
                    }
            
        }   
        

?>
```

Comment: Well, if it's doing what it's supposed to do I would assume you're doing it right...

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `$name_id`, so as such you normally wouldn't handle `$name_id` in its entirety within the loop. It is fairly unclear what you are trying to do, but as a first step you should be dealing with `array_values()` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You SQL query fetches the `note_id` field from your database -- and only that one.

Using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, each time the while loop iterates, `$data_row` will contain the data of one line of your notes table, which could be accessed using :

```
echo $data_row['note_id'] . '<br />';
```

So, your code might look like this :

```
$sql_for_username_submission = "SELECT note_id FROM notes WHERE user = '$username' ORDER BY note_id";
$get_data = mysql_query($sql_for_username_submission);
while ($data_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data))
{
    // $data_row contains the data for one entry in the DB
    // You could display $data_row here, to see what's in it :
    //print_r($data_row);
    echo $data_row['note_id'] . '<br />';
}
```

And if you want some additionnal data from the `notes` table, you'll have to select a couple more fields in your SQL query *(for instance)* :

```
$sql_for_username_submission = "SELECT note_id, your_value FROM notes WHERE user = '$username' ORDER BY note_id";
$get_data = mysql_query($sql_for_username_submission);
while ($data_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data))
{
    // $data_row contains the data for one entry in the DB
    // You could display $data_row here, to see what's in it :
    //print_r($data_row);
    echo $data_row['note_id'] . ' : ' . $data_row['your_value'] . '<br />';
}
```

i.e. no need for two loops : the `while` loop is enough to go through each line of data returned from the database -- and you can read each different column using `$data_row['name of the column']`.